# How do I get the posts within a certain year/date(with sql query)?

Tags: database, mysql, sql

Right now I have this:

```
SELECT guid FROM wp_posts 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT post_id as p FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE "_thumbnail_id") 
AND post_type = 'post'
AND post_date LIKE '%2016%'
```

I'm trying to get the permalinks of posts that do not have a feature image within x to y years. Is it possible to do something like:

```
AND post_date (get it from 2016-2017)
```

Comment: FYI, `guid` is not the same as the permalink and can't reliably be used as such. You need to load the WP environment and use the API to get a post's permalink.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for posts from last 1 year:

```
AND ( 
  post_date_gmt < DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  )
```